# Jquery: how to combine focus() and scrollTop()?

Tags: jquery

I need to combine focus() and scrollTop().

This works for focus():

```
    $(document.body).on("click",".comment_b",function() { 
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#textarea2-"+ID).focus();
return false;});
```

How can I add scrollTop() after focus()?

Comment: use the callback.. focus(function(){//your scrolltop code})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document.body).on("click",".comment_b",function() 
{ 
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#textarea2-"+ID).focus();
    $("#textarea2-"+ID).scrollTop(0);
    return false;
});
```

You can also use this

```
$(document.body).on("click",".comment_b",function() 
{ 
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#textarea2-"+ID).focus().scrollTop(0);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).on("click",".comment_b",function() { 
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#textarea2-"+ID).focus().scrollTop();
    return false;
});
```